# How create TS type nested?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My prototype

```
type cityType = {
  name:  string,
  type: number,
  coords: {
    x: number,
    y: number,
  },
  _id: string
}

type routeType = {
  city: cityType[],
  _id: string
}
```

But I have got error:

**This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'cityType' have no overlap**

I want `route  = [city1, city2, ...]`

Comment: You should show the block that causes the error too.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that routeType is an object, not an array.
Try

```
const route: routeType = {
  city: [city1, city2, ...],
  _id: 'something'
}
```